# Vue3 + Vite + Typescript: Scoped slots type error

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have project with following devstack (Vue3, Vite, TypeScript) and I'm getting a following error on `v-slot`:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"default"' can't be used to index type '{} | {}'.
  Property 'default' does not exist on type '{} | {}'.ts(7053)
```

```
<DataWrapper v-slot="{ values }">
  data: {{ values }}
</DataWrapper>
```

`DataWrapper` component injects props to the slot like this

```
...
<slot :values="data"></slot>
...
```

It does compile and works as expected but the error is still there. Any idea how to solve this? Thanks a million.

Comment: Where are you seeing the error? VS Code? If so, make sure you're using the Volar extension (instead of Vetur).

Comment: This is the first Vue3/Typescript 'any' error I've run up against without a stackoverflow solution, would hate to have to change the strictness level just to get this tiny bit compiling.

Comment: Oooo! Just realized, maybe there is a way to use //@ts-ignore in a very targetted way..

Comment: @sol I cannot reproduce the issue in this [repo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue3-ts-v-slot-props). Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: @sol, IMHO placing a bounty on this question is unlikely to provide you with a good answer. The question lacks context, we have no way of knowing how DataWrapper looks like (if it's a custom component, if it's a lib, what version of a lib, etc...). The only solution in cases like this is `any`, `any[]` or `unknown[]`, which is not much of a solution, really. You had more chances of getting a good answer by asking a separate question, with all the necessary details. The only possible answer for current question is: disable TS.

Comment: Related issue https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/893
I'm not sure exactly yet why this error occurs and how they fix it.

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried adding type information?

```
<DataWrapper v-slot="{ values }: { values: any }">
  data: {{ values }}
</DataWrapper>
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#property-renaming

If you are using eslint you can also surround the DataWrapper with

```
<!-- eslint-disable -->
<!-- eslint-enable -->
```

Comment: What Version of Vue is required for this to work? 
This results in a vue-loader-v15 error SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ","  with vue-cli 5.0.8

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Disable ESLint check for the whole Vue file
   `/* eslint-disable  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */`
2. Write it as a render function so that this:

```js
<template>
  <router-view
    v-slot="{Component}"
  >
    <transition
      name="fade"
      mode="out-in"
    >
      <component
        :is="Component"
        :key="$route.path"
      />
    </transition>
  </router-view>
</template>
```

becomes this:

```js
<template>
  <render />
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import {h, Transition} from "vue";
import {RouterView, useRoute} from "vue-router";
import type {VNode} from "vue";

const route = useRoute();
const render = () => {
  return h(RouterView, null, {
    default: ({Component}: {Component: VNode}) => {
      return h(Transition, {name: 'fade', mode: 'out-in'}, [
        h(Component, {key: route.path}),
      ]);
    },
  });
};
</script>
```