# How to set types to vue slot props Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, types, vuejs3, vue-props

I'm trying to set types on my slot props to handle in a table component as you can see in the image

[image]

I also have been trying with

`#body={item: UserItem}`, but it is only rename the parametter.
`#body={<UserItem>item}` and `#body={item<UserItem>}`, but it does not work

Answer (score 28):

The slot scope is an object so you need to type the object itself like

```
<template #body="{ item }: { item: UserItem }" />
```

But if the `Table` component is your own component you could also use `generic` in combination with `defineProps` and `defineSlots` to automatically infer the type for `item` in your slot based on the `values` prop that is passed in.

```
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T">
const props = defineProps<{
  values: T[]
}>()

const slots = defineSlots<{
  body(props: { item: T }): any
}>()
</script>
```

Comment: Hello Craig, thanks for your help, I think id working that way, but the Ts linter still got me this error `Can not find 'UserItem' ts(2304)`

Comment: Did you import `UserItem` into your component? It would be helpful if you updated your question with the complete source code.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `eslint-plugin-vue` throws `Parsing error: Unexpected token :.` on the first colon so I can't compile. The plugin is on the latest version as of writing (9.7.0) and I'm on Vue 2 if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Pyroglyph sounds like typescript might not be configured properly. If you need help with that I would ask a new question.

Comment: What Version of Vue is required for this to work?

Comment: This results in a `vue-loader-v15` error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "," `  with vue-cli 5.0.8

Comment: This question was specifically tagged as vue3. I'm not sure if this would work in older versions of vue.

Comment: Thanks @CraigHarshbarger, very useful.

Comment: This solution worked for me with vue3/nuxt3/typescript. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with [defineSlots](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineslots)

example:

```
 // in yout template

 <slot name="body" :msg="msg"></slot>

// in your script

defineSlots<{
  body(props: { msg: string }): any
}>()
```

and with that you will have msg as a string type

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to set types from the consumer side of a component that provides typed slots.

In OP's case, their component doesn't know the actual type of the content, but because a slot is used to provide the body, type info from the consumer is lost and needs to be re-cast. Other answers address this need but yours addresses a distinct one.

Answer (score 1):

Creating element as a render function can help to resolve the issue because you won't need to deal with typescript inside Vue template.
In render function you will be able to use types however you want.

Here is how your render function might look like:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <render />
  </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import {h} from "vue";
import {Table} from "...";

interface UserItem {
  name: string;
  id: string;
};

const values = {};

const render = () => {
  return h(Table, {values: values, cols: ["Name", "id"]}, {
    body: ({item}: {item: UserItem}) => [
      h('th', item.name),
      h('th', item.id)
    ],
  });
};
</script>
```

P.S.

I haven't tested the code but I wrote similar code that worked in my case.
See my another response related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75518154/5746474