# In Vue3 - Inferr a type to a slotProp from the modelValue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I have simplified the component I am trying to create:

```html
// MyComp.vue

<script setup lang="ts">
import { PropType, defineProps, defineEmits } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
    modelValue: {
        type: Array as PropType<unknown[]>,
        required: true,
    },
});

const emit = defineEmits({
    updateModelValue: (value: unknown[]) => true,
});
</script>

<template>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in modelValue" :key="index">
        <slot :item="item" :index="index"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

```html
// Parent.vue

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { MyComp } from '.';

const myArray = ref([
    {
        name: 'A',
        id: 1,
    },
    {
        name: 'B',
        id: 2,
    },
]);

</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <MyComp v-model="myArray">
            <template #default="{ item }">
                <!-- item is of type unknown - type not inferred :( -->
                <div>{{ item }} </div>
            </template>
        </MyComp >
    </div>
</template>
```

My problem is that the type of `item` does not get inferred, so I do not get the intelliSense I want.

How can I achieve this ?

<kbd>(StackOverflow would not let me post this question without more details, so I added this sentence)</kbd>

Comment: "item is of type unknown" - how do you know? By observing it in IDE? Because this is a problem that is primarily specific to IDE, not Vue in general. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72914927/how-to-set-types-to-vue-slot-props-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have literally set your array item type to `unknown`. I don't think there is anything left for TS to infer at that point.

If you are using Vue version 3.3 or above, you can use [generic components](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-3#generic-components):

```html
// MyComp.vue

<script setup lang="ts" generic="T">
import { PropType } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
    modelValue: {
        type: Array as PropType<T[]>,
        required: true,
    },
});

const emit = defineEmits({
    updateModelValue: (value: T[]) => true,
});
</script>
```

This will infer types correctly, see [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqFU81u2zAMfhXOOyQF4gRbb54TIB1y2IBuxRbsUvVgxHSmxpY0SU4TBH73UZLtOm2X+SKT/PjP7xQtlZrua4ySKDUbzZUFg7ZWUGZiO2eRNSxaMMErJbWFE2gsoIFCywpG5DbqTbfHz7JSrWU6c4KLO/rEBBMbKYyF6rjUOjvC3EUZ3zMB9J3C4z6RVZjAaDmaPOt4nsCHVm7a97XLzUuXjwOXhytfQzoL/VE3JFisVJlZJMnh0pzv218vtt3s40rmWNIc2tr9MDqUR3aB4H2ORVaXlsAn4KSG5hXae7yL42DnBmQB9qgQarET8klAHEQhLXBRoNaYQzKGOH4rkKv51OVqIJ2dN+ExsxeNBmXbXtd86zgARxPaPG2t4Nvpo5GCzsNPnUUbcuQl6u/Kctoqi5JuHyzKylI+ffU6q2tsd0A+v3Gze0P/aA5Ox6I7jQb1HlnU22ymt2iDefXzGx7ovzfSVuqS0BeMP9DIsnY1BthNLXIqe4Dz1X7x18vFdm1WB4vCdE25Qh0yHB2L6JbdzP7V+nO519Nr78dEQ1PseHCJX7BFgZpvSFyfs+1OS7V2BzGk3IBRiuyG+ESnxwU6tBm3JfnD/ZWVNfFjQBh3XgkEHmamT5Cu7x8WAw5p/FNzOr6zhblRNIFMIT1W3PbZVyT02WuV0xndDmoY78NLia5gvuji+nj/pSYRsZCa5jN2xz4hbuR4uKJn0CbNMdnhkUDeesa91JTEqMQ5Ozs9Du1xAzyVQbALpGj+AqPSny0=)

Comment: Thank you so much!   <3